# itextsharp output string with multiple rows

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, itext, phrase

This is the reference pdf I am trying to replicate.

http://www.depo.com.tw/asp/pdf/R_VW_PASAT_2.pdf

I am working on the PDF catalog and I am trying to output something like the red-text area.

As you guys can see in the PDF, outputting the letters **441-11B2-LDHEM** is very straightforward. However, outputting **441-11A7-LD/RD-EM1** is not.

```
private void PlaceChunck(String text, int x, int y)
{
    PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
    cb.SaveState();
    cb.BeginText();
    cb.MoveText(x, y);
    cb.ShowText(text);
    cb.EndText();
    cb.RestoreState();
}
```

All I can think of is place chunk at the corresponding areas.    But this is a really length process and requires much calculation of charaters...

I was wondering if anyone know how to do this in an easier way? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

OK, now I understand the question.

The best way to do this, is to create a small `PdfTemplate` object, and to add the LD and RD to it at the correct place (one above the other). Now wrap the `PdfTemplate` inside an `Image` object, and wrap the `Image` inside a `Chunk` (maybe with a Y offset).
Now you can create a `Phrase` with "441-11A7-", followed by the image Chunk, followed by "-EM1". Unfortunately, that's the simplest way I know.

Another way would be to use a `Chunk` with `setTextRise()`, but then you'd have to find a way to return a number of characters. While this may be possible, it's probably more difficult and more error-prone.

Finally, writing a custom implementation of the DrawInterface or VerticalMark could work, but I'd need more time to write such an example (time I currently don't have; I'm at the ISO committee for PDF in Vienna for the moment).

Maybe you can show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: lemme try this first.  I don't even know where to start my question I kept googling lines, rows, phrases, linebreaks and those keywords doesn't work... lemme check :)

Comment: also LD/RD is one case, there are so many cases such as -E/-R, -LED/-BUB..  can I do this case by case?

Comment: What about creating a PdfPTable with one row and three columns? You could vertically center the content which would give the desired effect. In any case: you're asking something that isn't a standard request ;-)

Comment: because I am making a catalog so I am already putting the phrases in table cells.. this is the problem @@

Comment: nest table can probable work but it seems different than what the pdf do. I do that but I cannot select the whole text anymore...

Comment: could you give me some suggestion where I can read more about PdfTemplate and putting strings into image chunk?  I researched so far and didn't see many examples....

Comment: Again, you've lost me: "I cannot select the whole text anymore"; that will always be the case whatever you try. I'm going to stop answering this question now. What you're asking isn't supported out-of-the-box; you'll have to accept this.

Comment: I mean if I want to select the text, I can only select the message inside one cell.   But judging from the pdf I can select the whole string so I think this is not how they did it..